# With justification, determine whether or not the following space is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, covering-spaces

The space in question is the Hausdorff topological space with base β:

β = {U(a, b) : a, b ∈ Z, b > 0}, where
U(a, b) = {a + kb : k ∈ Z} .

(I have confirmed that this in fact a base of a Hausdorff topology on Z)

I have now been asked to determine whether it is compact. In fact, I know that it is not compact, but do not know how to justify this.

My definition of compact is that a topological space X is compact if every open cover (Ui) with i in I, has a finite subcover. 
Hence I would appreciate any help in finding an open cover of the space, that has no finite subcover.

Comment: Hint: Look at prime numbers and use something like: every prime is of the form X or Y. And why do you "know" it? Someone told you or do you have any arguments/intuition?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\mathscr{U}=\{U(0,p):p\text{ is prime}\}$ covers $\Bbb Z\setminus\{-1,1\}$. (Why?) Find open sets $V$ and $W$ containing $-1$ and $1$, respectively, such that $\mathscr{U}\cup\{V,W\}$ has no finite subcover. You may find [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) useful.